# Umbraco (Examine) Search - Synonyms

Tags: umbraco, umbraco8, examine

I am trying to implement synonym searching in the Examine search engine that comes with Umbraco 8 out of the box.

Does anyone have any experience with implementing synonym searching in Examine/Umbraco 8. The options that I have been considering after looking around are -

- A package that can be installed in Umbraco 8 that offers this extended functionality (if one exists).
- Implementing a custom index (currently just using the out of the box 'ExternalIndex') that somehow implements synonym searching in the analysis (via custom analyzer implementation etc - If that is even possible).
- Manually formatting multiple search terms by checking for synonyms in the string beforehand, running all searches and consolidating the results after (really a nasty, last resort option - you don't have to tell me how bad this is, I already know).

I have been trawling around the forums for a definitive answer on this and cannot really find one. Essentially I want to stick with the Examine engine for simplicity, however I am starting to think that the best way to achieve what I am after would be to move to a new engine completely (elastic search for example).

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Examine is based on something called the Lucene search index.  Lucene is known to not really do synonyms I'm afraid [(read why here and potential solution](https://lucidworks.com/post/solution-for-multi-term-synonyms-in-lucenesolr-using-the-auto-phrasing-tokenfilter/)).

Your thinking is probably correct.  Examine is good at what it does, if you want to use more advanced searching then you will be better off using a more advanced search provider.  There are loads of options, Algolia is Saas and comes with a free plan depending on your usage.  It's easy to install and you target data from the front-end.

YOu could also look into Azure Cognitive Search or Solr.   These are probably harder to implement but will also do the job